# Convert input string to date in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, macintosh, parameter

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1";
startd=$(date -d "$1" +"%Y%m%d"); 
echo "$startd";
```

My command:

> sudo ./test.sh "20151010"

The output:

```
20151010 
20150213
```

it printed todays date instead of printing the input date any idea?

Comment: Be warned: date -d with sudo might change system date in OSX

Comment: I have no such problem with `date` under Linux. You may need to install the GNU Coreutils and use `date` from them. BTW, you do not need `sudo`.

Comment: The OS X version of `date` doesn't parse arbitrary date formats like the GNU version does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OS X version of `date` uses the `-f` option to parse a formatted date/time:

```
date -j -f '%Y%m%d' "$1" +'%Y%m%d'
```

The `-j` option causes it to just print the time, not try to set the system clock. So the full script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1";
startd=$(date -j -f '%Y%m%d' "$1" +'%Y%m%d'); 
echo "$startd";
```

Here's a transcript:

```
$ ./testdate.sh 20151010
20151010
20151010
```

Comment: it turns out developing these scripts on osx won't do for me than because production env is linux, And i want the linux version of scripts

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to format date on OS X, you can try this:

```
date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "20151010"
```

I get the following output:

```
Sat Oct 10 17:27:28 CDT 2015
```